# Can you use universal instantiation to equate two universal quantifiers on the same scope?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

As seen in the answer for [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2482053/universal-instantiation-with-universal-quantifiers-within-scope), not every statement can be safely instantiated. For example, given the statement $\forall x P(x)\rightarrow Q$, it does not follow that $P(a) \rightarrow Q$.

Suppose I have the following:
$$ \exists A \exists B \forall x \forall y \ \Omega(A,B,x,y) $$

Can I safely instantiate $y$ to be $x$, such that, given the previous statement, the following holds:
$$ \exists A \exists B \forall x \ \Omega(A,B,x,x) $$

If not, when can I be sure that it is safe to instantiate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule for [Universal Instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation) is, in general:

> $∀xα → α[t/x]$.

This is simply: "if everything is $P$, then $t$ is $P$", for every object $t$.

But there is a proviso: "provided that term $t$ is *substitutable for* variable $x$ in $\alpha$ that means: provided that term $t$ has no occurrences of variables that will be "captured" by a quantifier in $\alpha$.

This proviso is needed in order to avoid the following fallacy:

> from $∀x∃y(x<y)$, derive $∃y(y<y)$.

---

Regarding the example with $∀x∀y[x=y∨x≠y]$, how can we apply safely UI ?

1. $∀x∀y[x=y∨x≠y]$ --- premise
2. $∀y[z=y∨z≠y]$ --- from 1) by UI (we have to instantiate the outermost quantifier first)
3. $[z=z∨z≠z]$ --- from 2) by UI

> 4. $∀z[z=z∨z≠z]$ --- from 3) by [UG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization).

---

A comment, regarding the order of quantifiers.

In general, $\forall x \forall y \alpha \equiv \forall y \forall x \alpha$, and the same for the existential one.

Thus, in a nutshell for "adjacent" equal quantifiers the order does not matter.

This is not so for $\forall x \exists y$.

---

---

A final comment showing why $\forall x P(x) \to Q \nvDash P(a) \to Q$.

Consider the domain $\mathbb N$ of *natural* numbers, and let $P(x)$ the formula: $(x > 0)$ and let $Q$ the formula $(1=0)$. Finally, let $a$ the term $1$.

We have that $\forall x (x > 0)$ is False in $\mathbb N$ and $(1=0)$ is False also. Thus $\forall x (x > 0) \to (1=0)$ is True in $\mathbb N$.

But $(1 > 0) \to (1 = 0)$ is not.

Comment: Thanks man, great answer. Specially the example on how to use it (and UG) on ∀x∀y[x=y∨x≠y]